# Transition du s latin au é en français moderne en début de mot

Tags: étymologie, origine-ou-raison, comparaison-de-langues, évolution, ancien-français

(Version courte ci-dessous)

#### Motivations

Un collègue m'a fait remarquer une similarité entre des mots anglais et français où le français semble avoir un **é** en début de mot, là où l'anglais utilise un **s**, par exemple:

- **é**trange / **s**trange
- **é**pice / **s**pice
- **é**tudiant / **s**tudent
- ...

En y réfléchissant un peu plus, je me suis rappelé qu'en espagnol, beaucoup d'entre eux commencent par **es** (**es**tudiante, **es**pecias, ...) me suis demandé si c'était également le cas en ancien français et que le français aurait suivi le chemin **es** -> **é** tandis que l'anglais aurait simplement "perdu" le **e**.

Du coup, j'ai recherché l'[étymologie](https://www.cnrtl.fr/etymologie) de certains mots (par exemple de [cette liste](https://www.motsavec.com/search.php?i=%C3%A9&f=&ms=&mns=&m=&mn=&fs=0&fs2=0&fnl=0&fnl2=0&fa=0&ju=0&d=3&tv=4&Submit=Chercher)).

Les quelques exemples choisis indiquent effectivement la présence du **s** à l'espagnole au 10-14è siècle. Par contre, l'origine latine présente souvent un **s** seul. Exemples:

- étudiant -> estudian (1261) -> studiere
- épi -> espi (1606) -> spicum / spica
- écu -> escut (1100) -> scutum
- épée -> spede (800) -> spatha
- épice -> espice (1365) -> species
- écrire -> escrit (1050) -> scribere
- état -> estate (1213) -> statu

« Étrange » fait exception (estrange (1050) -> extranus).

Il est à noter que d'autres mots n'ont pas suivi cette transition. Par exemple: spécial -> especïel (1160) / special (1165) -> specialis. Alors que l'espagnol a gardé **es**pecial.

#### TL;DR

Ma question :

- Y a-t-il des travaux de recherche détaillant l'apparente évolution du **s** (latin) au **es** (ancien français/espagnol moderne) puis au **é** (français moderne) ?

Et peut-être, tant qu'on y est (même si ça pourrait être discuté sur un autre "stack") :

- L'anglais, pour ces mots, emprunte-t-il au français ancien, ou directement au latin ?

Comment: La seconde partie de la question concerne un autre site SE, mais sa réponse est facilement obtenue à partir de l'étymologie d'un dictionnaire comme le Shorter Oxford. Par exemple, on trouve que  "strange" est obtenu par aphérèse (aphesis) du vieux français "estrange".Cela n'est pas à généraliser cependant : "student" trouve sa forme directement dans le latin "student-" pres.ppl. stem of studere).

Comment: @LPH, j'ai modifié le texte pour mettre plus d'importance sur la première partie.

Answer (score 6):

Le E(S) à l'initiale de mots français a trois raisons possibles :

- le préfixe français ES dérivé du préfixe latin EX (*ébahi*)
- le préfixe latin EX transformé selon les habitudes de la prononciation française.(*étrange*)
- **la pro(s)thèse du E** (l'addition de e devant sc, sp, st) (*écrire*)

Il semble que c'est ce dernier cas qui t'intéresse.

Il est difficile de faire une étude synthétique de ce phénomène linguistique sans s'ancrer :

- Dans un lieu. Une région. (Tu parles du français, de l'espagnol... mais le catalan préfèrera souvent un A au E (*ASKOLA* (schola))
- Dans une époque. (de nombreux mots pourtant de même origine seront traités différemment simplement parce qu'ils sont plus tardifs.

Ainsi *Estomac* mais *Stomachique* / *Esprit* mais *Spirituel* / *Espace* mais *Spacieux*... Pour ce qui est du français... alors que l'espagnol semble s'y tenir à l'époque moderne jusque dans l'adaptation des anglicismes (*stress* / *stand*...)

Saussure s'y est néanmoins essayé en proposant (dans son cours de linguistique générale) une explication de type articulatoire.

Mais je dirais bien pour ma part qu'à chaque mot son histoire particulière... et c'est peut-être à cela que servent des ouvrages comme le DHLF.
De nombreuses pages en ont été numérisées sur GG books, avec un peu de bol... tu peux espérer trouver ton bonheur.